# How to hide and show a div in react js

Tags: reactjs

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I don't really understand the answer mainly because all the answer use "Class" and I was taught to use function. I don't even understand the difference but every time I try using a class component, nothing works.

I am really new to React.js and I have a hard time understanding how it works.

I need to show and hide `-  <p className='service_explication more'>{props.more}</p> -` on the click of a button with a smooth animation. 
I've tried with basic javascript but it doesn't work. 
I've tried a lot of things and now I am stuck and I don't find a good explanation to what I need.

Could you please help me ? I really want to learn but I'm having a hard time.

Thank you so much for your help.

````
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../assets/Section.scss';
import '../assets/Services.scss';

function Services(){




      function showMore(event){




    }

    const BlocService = (props) => {
    return <div className='service_sub_container'>
        <h1 className='service_name'>{props.name}</h1>
        <p className='service_explication'>{props.explication}</p>
        <p className='service_explication more'>{props.more}</p>
        <button onClik={showMore}>Plus</button>    
    </div>
    }




    return (

        <>
        <div className='main_container'>
            <div className='section_container'>
                <div className='title_intro_container'>
                    <h1 className='section_title'>Nos Services</h1>
                    <p className='section_intro'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sequi alias iste ducimus tenetur saepe reprehenderit quasi reiciendis ab architecto.</p>
                 </div>

                <div className='service_container'>
                    <BlocService name={'Développeur Front/Web'} explication={'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sequi alias iste ducimus tenetur saepe reprehenderit quasi reiciendis ab architecto.'} />
                    <BlocService name={'Lead developper'} explication={'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sequi alias iste ducimus tenetur saepe reprehenderit quasi reiciendis ab architecto.'} />
                    <BlocService name={'Architectes Front-end'} explication={'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sequi alias iste ducimus tenetur saepe reprehenderit quasi reiciendis ab architecto.'} />
                    <BlocService name={'Développeur Front/Web'} explication={'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sequi alias iste ducimus tenetur saepe reprehenderit quasi reiciendis ab architecto.'} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </>

    );
}

export default Services;```
````

Comment: Which div are you trying to show/hide?

Comment: I explain myself wrong. I want to show and hide <p className='service_explication more'>{props.more}</p>

Comment: OK, you should put BlockService in a separate file. Right now there is only one `showMore` in `Services` but you need to move it to the BlockService component and toggle a state to show/hide some div

Comment: I posted an answer with the full code for the `BlocService` component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything can be done inside the BlocService component. Using a state and conditional rendering:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const BlocService = (props) => {
    const [more, setMore] = useState(false);

    const showMore = () => {
        setMore(!more);
    }

    return (
        <div className='service_sub_container'>
            <h1 className='service_name'>{props.name}</h1>
            <p className='service_explication'>{props.explication}</p>
            {more && <p className='service_explication more'>{props.more}</p>}
            <button onClick={showMore}>Plus</button>    
        </div>
    )
}

export default BlocService;
```

You also have to remove `showMore` from `Services`

Comment: So I need to create a BlocService.jsx and then call it inside Service.jsx ?

Comment: Yes, it's better to have each component in its own file

Comment: I put it in another file but it is not working .. Should I surround it with a function ?

Comment: You need to import React at the beginning of the file and export the component at the end, I just updated my answer

Comment: Then inside `Services`, you can add `import BlocService from './BlocService'`

Comment: That's what I did, the BlocService component is displayed on the screen but the toggle button is not working ...

Comment: There is a typo in the button code, change `onClik` to `onClick`

Comment: Wow, i am just blind ! I am so sorry for abusing your time like that. thank you so much for your time and your help :)

Comment: Pas de souci, avec plaisir :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't feel bad for ask, everyone has to learn from the bottom.

Reactjs works making "renders" of the webpage in a dynamic way, so you have 2 options depending if you want a smooth animation or just a default show/hide.

1. If you want to show in a easy way, you can just make a condition which allows to create or not the desired div

   ```
   function Component() {
       const [showed, setShowed] = useState(false)
       return (
           <div>
               <button onClick={()=>setShowed(!showed)}>Show/Hide</button>
               {showed && <div>HELLO</div>}
           </div>
       )
   }
   ```
2. If you want to create smooth animations you might want to need classes. With React you can just add or remove classes with no problem and let css do the job, so you can make

   ```
   function Component() {
       const [showed, setShowed] = useState(false)
       return (
           <div>
               <button onClick={()=>setShowed(!showed)}>Show/Hide</button>
               <div className={showed?classShowed:classHided>HELLO</div>
           </div>
       )
   }
   ```

   I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

In a functional component you would control state by the `useState` hook provided by react.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function() services {

    const [show, toggleText] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Header text</h2>
            <button onClick={toggleText(!show)}>Toggle text button</button>
            {show && (<p>Text to toggle</p>)}
        </div>
    )

}
```

[React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)